# Vagrant & Virtualbox in Windows 10; Error renaming connection

Tags: networking, vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox, shopware

I tried to [run a vagrant setup](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/shopware-vagrant) using the latest versions of Vagrant VirtualBox and windows 10 (latest update):

`Vagrant 1.8.6
VirtualBox 5.1.8 r111374 (Qt5.5.1)`

If I set in my Vagrant file 

`config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"`

I get this error:

```
Error renaming connection: 
Cannot rename this connection. A connection with the name you specified already exists. Specify a different name.
```

[image]

Sofar I tried installing/removing both vagrant and virtualbox, I even downgraded and upgraded.. Restarted my compuiter several times, switched off my proxy, followed every crazy hack out there but I always get that error.

I even went to regedit and deleted all the related keys there but no success!

The output of the console:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Assertion failed: [!aInterfaceName.isEmpty()] at 'F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (74) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Bstr,class com::Bstr,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0038).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Please contact the product vendor!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: So, this is a configuration/administration question, which is off-topic for SO. Also, it's bad to post screenshots of text rather than copying the text to the question itself. Also, it is bad to use tags that you don't even mention in your question (shopware, in this case). Also, you've got more than 5k reputation and should know better!

Comment: I never tagged it as hardware, I only removed the unmentioned shopware tag. Yes, I know Vagrant and VirtualBox. Yes, I evaluate the following to know whether a question is on-topic: **Is this a question related to programming?** Your question is **not** related to programming. You have a problem with VirtualBox, which is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0):

After some deep researching on this issue, I finally found two things that should be done:

1. I cleared existing VM machines and deleted those folders `C:\Users\{user}\.VirtualBox` and `C:\Users\{user}\VirtualBox VMs` restart the computer.
2. Whenever I changed the IP address of the machine, I run `vagrant halt && vagrant reload && vagrant up --provision`

This fixed the issue.